# Disable text selection onclick button

Tags: html, css

How can I avoid that there is a dotted selection rectangle around the text when the user clicks the button, see image below. I already tried to add the css rule `user-select: none;`, which I saw in another question, but this doesn't seem to work.

[image: rectangle around the text when the user clicks the button]

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: The issue only appears in Firefox (tested with version 47.0)**

```css
.button {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  border: none;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;/* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #595959;
  /* Green */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: `outline: none;` but sometimes it's usefull ..

Comment: There is not selection in your code snipped. To you have the problem in all browsers?

Comment: I tested it with Opera, Chrome and Firefox. Only in Firefox appears this rectangle. (I used latest versions of all browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remove the dotted border in buttons in Firefox:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: This works. But why do I have to do this in firefox? Other browsers didn't add the dotted border on click

Comment: Is for accesibility reasons. From MDN: "Firefox will add, for accessibility purposes, a small dotted border on a focused button. This border is declared through CSS, in the browser stylesheet, but you can override it if necessary to add your own focused style using `button::-moz-focus-inner { }`" [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this in your CSS :

```
.yourclass
{
outline:none;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```